# Real time update with nodejs and memcached

Tags: php, node.js, memcached

I have a nodejs server with a socket.io, which are broadcasting data. Data I'm trying to get from memchached. Everything works well, but I want to create a live broadcasting.
This data are updating by a php side. How I can retrieve this data in nodejs when its changing by php? May be callback for nodejs side or event triggering ?
My current code but its not live.

Php:

```
$mem = new Memcached();
$mem->addServer("127.0.0.1", 11211);    
$mem->set($key, "customdata", 10);
```

Nodejs:

```
var Memcached = require('memcached');
var memcached = new Memcached('127.0.0.1:11211');
memcached.gets('key', function (err, result) {
  console.log(result.key); 
})
```

Comment: As far as I know, Memcached is not built for pub/sub. You could achieve best results with Redis pub/sub http://redis.io/topics/pubsub which works like a charm.

Comment: @jpaljasma yes, I did example (redis new for me) and its working, I think thats what I need) thank you